# Arduino mega board 5v pin does not gives 5v when 7.5v is applied through external source

Tags: arduino-mega, power, usb, pins, hardware

I gave 7.5v to the arduino mega board through battery. 5v pin in the board gives me the same voltage as input. Earlier it was working fine now it is giving problem.Please let me know the solution as soon as possible.

Thanks and regards,
Thippeswamy

Comment: Where are you applying the power? on the barrel jack? Where are you measuring the voltage? How? (explain it as clearly as possible, example: I put two wires, one in the 5V pin and one in the GND pin, then attach the two wires to the multimeter set in DC with a 20V range and it reads 7.5V). Moreover do you have a cheap USB power bank?

Answer (score 1):

If you apply 7.5V to the power barrel jack and the 5V pin is 7.5V then your Arduino board is broken. Don't connect it to a computer. Don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that you have destroyed your Arduino. This can happen in a number of ways. Rugged Circuits has a great article on [10 ways you can destroy the Arduino](https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/).

The giveaway is that you are measuring 7.5V on the 5V pin. Most likely the voltage regulator has blown. Page 355 of the [ATMega2560 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) says the absolute maximum voltage for the chip is 6.0V, so this also means that the microcontroller is blown as well. It is most likely unsalvageable.

Go out and buy yourself a new one. Before you turn it on, check the wiring is correct.

We have all let the [magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) out at some point.

Comment: The link to rugged circuits is broken.

Comment: Hmm... it worked for me. https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/